# iPhone UIPickerView issue

Tags: iphone

Friends
 I have problem in horizontal UIPickerView. Can some one help me to short this problem out? 
Actually I got the horizontal picker view but I have problem with data array inside picker view is not clear,its visibility is not good I show you picture what exactly i want sorry i cant add so please help me out.

[image]
This is my code:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 30);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);
        rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 2.0, 2.0);
        [label setTransform:rotate];
        label.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];

        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.numberOfLines = 2;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:22];
        label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.clipsToBounds = YES;
        return label ;
}
```

Comment: add the picture to some free uploading site..and give me the link..i will upload it then

Comment: this is the link of image and all small gray color is label  http://i40.tinypic.com/t020k7.png

Comment: You won't be able to upload image as your rep points are below 15

Comment: Thanks Shubhank you have solution of this I got every thing but my data is not clear when I have increase scale its looks too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't scale your label by 2x by using `CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 2.0, 2.0)` that's why it's not pixel perfect clear, if you want a bigger label, you should double the font size. And replace 3.14 with constant `M_PI`